# Auto layout show button round without fixing height and width

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I am very new to iOS development and have never done auto layout before ,I have actually seven buttons on a view controller that needs to look round on every screen without fixing height and width....I have looked many tutorials but couldn't understand that how I can add constraints on those round buttons  and show them at same position on every screen. I want the buttons to actually increase size when screen increase and decrease when screen size decreases.Please help and show which constraints should be added.![this shows how buttons are added on my view controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gsYw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want perfect round buttons(circle) then width and height should be same. For that set the aspect constraint with multipler 1:1 so that width and height will become equal.

Based on the the screenshot you have provided, see below how the constraints should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, two points:

- Position: Well, you need understand accurately ‘same position in every screen’, I guess you know `view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, 50, 50)`but same code not lead to 'same position' in different screen, important thing is which way you want. Think about a increasing screen, you have a square on it, what do you want this square change? Different change style lead to different code.
- Size: You said you want square increasing or decreasing with screen, the basic way is let `square.width && square.height` changing with screen, if use frame layout you may write `view.frame = CGRectMake(10, 20, SCWidth * 0.0666, SCHeight * 0.0833)`, certainly autoLayout support scale calculate, I recommend you use **Masonry** to add layout, sample code like:

`[square mas_remakeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
            make.width.equalTo(self.mas_width).multipliedBy(0.0083);
}];`

of course if you use xib to do it, you can see constraints have **multiplier** property to fix problem.

Answer (score -2):

Use this code to make round button..
You can programmatically get the current height of Button and then assign the half of height to corner radius to make it round.

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[self.view setNeedsLayout];
self.yourButton.layer.cornerRadius = self.yourButton.frame.size.height/2;
self.yourButton.clipsToBound = YES;
```

Comment: i have already made it round....but I want it to appear it at same position ,increasing or decreasing height and width as required on every screen.